# Winston Module Not Found

Tags: node.js, express

Error: Cannot find module 'winston'
I am getting Above Error.How Can I Resolve This Error
I have already installed winston
const winston = require('winston');

Comment: do you see winston inside the node_modules folder?

Answer (score 1):

Did you install 'winston' via package manager?
This error message means that you're not.

Before use any package there's need to provide it to the project by installing via npm or by putting it manually to the node_module folder.

Seems like you just need to run a command

```
npm install winston
```

Comment: I have already  installed winston from npm

Comment: You have automaticaly created `package.json` file inside your working directory. Check if 'dependency' node contains 'winston' in the list.